# Remove rows with values repeated on specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a Dataframe of user reviews as the following:

```
Index   User   Location  Rating Langauge
    1    bob     62.354    4       eng
    2    bil     59.511    5       span
    3    bob     63.884    3       ger
    4    juan    58.221    4       jap
    5    bil     59.511    5       eng
    6    bil     57.422    5       fra
```

I'm trying to eliminate duplicate rows or reviews given that they are equal in the 'User' and 'Location' columns.

My desired output would be something like this:

```
Index   User   Location  Rating Language
    1    bob     62.354    4       eng
    2    bil     59.511    5       span
    3    bob     63.884    3       ger 
    4    juan    58.221    4       jap 
    6    bil     57.422    5       fra
```

Where the 5th row got deleted because it was a duplicate of the second row, given that the 'User' and 'Location' columns on both were the same. Keep in mind that usernames are unique to users and the location is unique to a place. Other variables are just categorical.

Thank you. This has been driving me crazy.

Comment: You need `df = df.drop_duplicates(['User','Location'])`, it is dupe :(

Comment: Thank you. Did not how to word it correctly and therefore could not find it.

Comment: Yes, I understand you. The hardest is know what is necessary use for keywords...

Comment: Anyway, worked like a charm. So thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome, you can upvote my solution in dupe, thanks.